# TypeError in python 3.x ('int' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

```
GTIN0 = int(GTIN[0])
```

brings up the error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

can someone explain to me why this happens, can you use simple terms as I'm not too experienced at coding so I'm not "in" with the code terms

Comment: what is in GTIN[0]

Comment: It means that `GTIN` is already an integer and you can use subscription on that (`[0]` is subscription).

Answer (score 0):

whatever `GTIN` is, it's not a list or string and it seems to be an integer so therefore there is no subscripting available. The `TypeError` states that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GTIN is an integer rather than a list or tuple, so the interpreter is trying to tell you that you can't take element 0 of an integer because it's not a container type.

How did `GTIN` acquire its value, and why do you think it should be subscriptable?